# MySQL - Size Limits to Integer Columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, integer

I'm using phpMyAdmin to create my table structures.

I can read from the documentation pages on MySQL about size limits for Integer Types:
[MySQL Integer Types Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/integer-types.html)

---

So here is where I'm getting a little confused with creating a column.

I want to create a column in the table: `tbl_note_categories` called `notescounter`

I don't foresee myself creating thousands of noteids in the `tbl_notes` with any specific `categoryid`.  But I do believe I'd create hundreds of notes to each categoryid.

I'm at that point of choosing between: tinyint, smallint, mediumint.
According the documentation link above, I'm guessing smallint is my best choice.

So here's my confusion.  PhpMyAdmin asks for a **Length/Values** parameter to be specified.
I'm going to make sure this new column (`notescounter`) is unsigned, giving me up to 65536.
Does that mean I need the Length/Values to be (5)?

I'm guessing Length is character length, but I'm not sure. (comparing to varchar)

[image: Snapshot of New column in PhpMyadmin]

Answer (score 57):

No, this is a common misconception about MySQL.  In fact, the "length" has no effect on the size of an integer or the range of values it can store.

- `TINYINT` is always 8 bits and can store 2<sup>8</sup> distinct values.
- `SMALLINT` is always 16 bits and can store 2<sup>16</sup> distinct values.
- `INT` is always 32 bits and can store 2<sup>32</sup> distinct values.
- `BIGINT` is always 64 bits and can store 2<sup>64</sup> distinct values.

There's also a MEDIUMINT, but the engineers who work on MySQL tell me MEDIUMINT always gets promoted to a 32-bit INT internally, so there's actually no benefit to using MEDIUMINT.

The length is *only* for display, and this only matters if you use the `ZEROFILL` option.

See an example in my answer to [What is the difference (when being applied to my code) between INT(10) and INT(12)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632403/what-is-the-difference-when-being-applied-to-my-code-between-int10-and-int1/1632567#1632567)

Comment: what about mediumInteger?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan: 24 bits, it can store 2^24 distinct values. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html But I never use them, since a MySQL engineer told me that mediumints are always stored as 32-bit objects internally. There's no storage savings by using mediumint.

Comment: Do you know why `BOOL`/`BOOLEAN` is defined as `TINYINT(1)`, not `BIT(1)`?

Comment: @SolomonUcko: For backward compatibility. In MySQL the `BIT(n)` datatype wasn't added until version 5.0. In MySQL 4.1 and earlier, `BOOL` and `BIT` (with no length option) were both synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to update it because in older versions it could be a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`, and in newer versions it could be a synonym for `BIT(1)`.

Comment: @SolomonUcko, well, when you run software development for an RDBMS, you can make that decision. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you want to specify a length of 5.

In MySQL, the "length" attribute on the integer types is optional. It's a MySQL extension which is non-standard).

When it is omitted from the column declaration, MySQL provides a default value.  For a SMALLINT UNSIGNED, the default value is 5.

This value does NOT have any impact on the range of values that can be stored for an integer type.  It specifies a "display length", which is returned in resultset metadata, which a client can choose to use or ignore.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html