# MySQL - Setting Integer Length

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, integer

I'm using `PhpMyAdmin` to set my table structures.

As I'm learning to use the columns correctly, I'm curious about choosing the right `integer` type, and most importantly the Length (`phpmyadmin` requires it)

From the [DZone.com](http://sql.dzone.com/news/making-your-mysql-tables-more-) I've read this:

Field Type Breakdown
 INT             0 to 4,294,967,295
 TINYINT     0 to 255
 SMALLINT    0 to 65535
 MEDIUMINT   0 to 16,777,215
 BIGINT          0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

And that helps me decide which `integer` type I'm most likely to use.
From the chart, I believe I need the SMALLINT, as I need more than 255.

But as I prepare it in `phpmyadmin`, I'm required to enter a Length/Value.

[image: Choosing Integer Type in Phpmyadmin]

If I'm sure my ID's won't get higher than 3000, do I put the number 4 in the Length/Value box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the 4 will accept the values of 4 integers so it can be 4 yes. the values will be accepted till 9999

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573451/mysql-size-limits-to-integer-columns?rq=1) can help you

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect. The length property for integers  is used for display purposes only in conjunction with the zerofill property and does not restrict the value iyou can store in it.

Answer (score 6):

its called the display size. The actual length of the values are not changed in any way so an int of length 5 and an int with no length will take up the same space.

Comment: So the chosen answer is incorrect? --> "the 4 will accept the values of 4 integers"

Comment: Yes. From the manual "The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column"

Answer (score 1):

The INT argument only applies to display width. Passing a value into INT() is simply there for display size as others have noted. Unless using the attribute ZEROFILL then you will experience zero-padding as opposed to space-padding without the ZEROFILL attribute.

Short answer just leave it blank if you don't fully understand what padding is being applied when you pass a value into INT().

Passing a value for the integer type argument will not show noticeable changes unless using the ZEROFILL attribute which uses zero-padding, this result will be equal to the number of digits specified in the int type argument.

Check out this answer by Bill Karwin for more in depth documentation. [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14573482/11389581)