# add new field in mysql table , its datatype and length must as same as other old field

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to add new column in mysql table but condition is new column must same as other old column(same table).

like old column have int data type and its length is 5

i want to add new column but new column datatype and length must same as old column.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: what do u mean by old and new column?

Comment: i  want to add new column but new column datatype and length must same as old column ?  this is my question. please help me.

Comment: myold column(field) is  =   age1 int  5                               i want to create new column(field)   =  age2  int 5

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD COLUMN `age2` INT;
```

The "length" doesn't matter. INT is INT. It's a common misconception that the argument to an INT type is some sort of "length" or "size". It's not.

See [MySQL - Size Limits to Integer Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573451/mysql-size-limits-to-integer-columns/14573482#14573482)