# MySQL - phpmyadmin alert message

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE `projekt_ti_cdv`.`offer` ( `offer_id` INT(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `offer_type` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL , `offer_price` INT(256) NOT NULL , `offer_realization` INT(256) NOT NULL , `offer_any_daw` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , `offer_vst` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`offer_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I tried to create table on my database and i got an alert message from localhost 'Please enter a valid length'. I don't know how to fix that.

BR,
Chris

Comment: Is this anything to do with SQL Server?

Comment: It may be worth reading up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573451/mysql-size-limits-to-integer-columns about the different type of ints and how it stores the data.

Comment: Do not specify the length for integer datatype - it is ignored anyway.

Comment: Is this SQL that was generated by phpMyAdmin after you filled in the graphical form for creating a new table?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length allowed for the `INT` datataype is 255. You need to fix that in your statement.

I am unsure that you do want to specify a length anyway. The `INT` size is always 4 bytes, regardless of the specified length - the length is just here to specify the padding that is used when displaying the values in the command line client.

I would recommend:

```
CREATE TABLE `projekt_ti_cdv`.`offer` ( 
    `offer_id` TINYINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `offer_type` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL , 
    `offer_price` INT NOT NULL , 
    `offer_realization` INT NOT NULL , 
    `offer_any_daw` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    `offer_vst` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`offer_id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I changed the datatype of column `offer_id` to `TINYINT`, since you seem to want a smaller number for this: it can store values up to 127 (or 255 when unsigned). See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) for more about integer datatypes storage and ranges.