# mysql, BIGINT value is out of range

Tags: mysql, integer-overflow

I looked at some of the other answers for similar questions but none of them seemed to help me.

```
  [2020-01-28 23:26:29] CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT value is out of range in 'count(`Um3mpV1OJwy6m`.`jobsubmits`.`id`) * 500000 * 4398046511104'
[2020-01-29 00:26:47] CronjobController::actionRun 0
[2020-01-29 00:27:07] CDbException#1
(
    [errorInfo] => array
    (
        0 => '22003'
        1 => 1690
        2 => 'BIGINT value is out of range in \'count(`Um3mpV1OJwy6m`.`jobsubmits`.`id`) * 500000 * 4398046511104\''
    )
    [*:message] => 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT value is out of range in \'count(`Um3mpV1OJwy6m`.`jobsubmits`.`id`) * 500000 * 4398046511104\''
    [Exception:string] => ''
    [*:code] => 22003
    [*:file] => '/home/crypto-data/yiimp/site/web/framework/db/CDbCommand.php'
    [*:line] => 543
    [Exception:trace] => array
```

Comment: What not to understand? Your number is too large for `BIGINT`.  Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632312/is-bigint8-the-largest-integer-mysql-can-store

Comment: bigint goes from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, so it is limited

Comment: What I dont understand is exactly how to fix it, :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when you need integers larger than 20 digits on mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142604/what-to-do-when-you-need-integers-larger-than-20-digits-on-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Your value is the COUNT() multiplied by:

```
500000 * 4398046511104 = 2199023255552000000
```

Max value of a signed BIGINT is 2<sup>63</sup>-1 = 9223372036854775807

```
9223372036854775807 / 2199023255552000000 = 4.1943
```

So if your COUNT() is greater than 4, then it will exceed the max value that can be represented in a signed BIGINT.